# probability of job in firms

Tags: probability

a chartered accountant applies for a job in two firms X and Y.He estimates that the probability of his being selected in the firm X is 0.7 and being rejected in Y is 0.5 and the probability that at least one of his applications rejected is 0.6.What is the probability that he will be selected in one of the firms?

Comment: Can you show us, what you have done so far?

Comment: Try tranlating the text into equations. For example: P(X)=0.7. You will need joins and unions. Can you write the rest 2 sentences as equations? And then the desired probability? Do you know a formula to connect all these 4 equations? How far can you get?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? It is already solved: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29281/probability-that-he-will-be-selected-in-one-of-the-firms. However try answering my questions before looking the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the event the he gets selected in the firm X and $Y$ be the event the he gets selected in the firm Y.

$$
P(X) = 0.7 \\
P(\overline{Y}) = 0.5 \implies P(Y) = 1-0.5 = 0.5\\
P(\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}) = 0.6 \implies P(X \cap Y) = 1-0.6 = 0.4 \\
P(X \cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X \cap Y) = 0.7 + 0.5 - 0.4 = 0.8
$$

The probability that he will be selected in "at least" one of the firms is $P(X \cup Y) = 0.8$ 
If you want the probability that he will be selected in "only one" of the firms, then it will
$P(X \cup Y) - P(X \cap Y)$ (give this a thought) = 0.8 - 0.4 = 0.4